# Tabulator Row Number Auto-Refresh / Update

Tags: javascript, row-number, tabulator

I'm aware of the builtin rownum formatter in Tabulator, and it works well, however as per the documentation formatters are only called when the data changes, hence enabling drag-and-drop then moving a row will leave the row sequence out of order.

Is there anyway to force an auto-refresh or otherwise regenerate the table row numbers after a drag-and-drop?

Many thanks,

Shaun

Comment: You will have to be very specific with a working example for any one to help yyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a limitation with older versions of Tabulator, as of version 4.5 released at the end of 2019, this issue was resolved.

the ***rownum*** formatter will not correctly update to match the data when the table config changes